# How to avoid Clang-Tidy warning when using QLibrary::resolve?

Tags: c++, qt, clang-tidy

[QLibrary documentation](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qlibrary.html) suggests casting the `QFunctionPointer` returned to a specific function pointer. However, following code results in a Clang-Tidy warning "Do not use C-style cast to convert between unrelated types":

```cpp
using FooFactory = Foo* ();
QLibrary lib(somePath);
const auto createFoo = (FooFactory*) lib.resolve("createFoo");
```

Using a `reinterpret_cast` instead, Clang-Tidy tells me "Do not use reinterpret_cast":

```cpp
using FooFactory = Foo* ();
QLibrary lib(somePath);
const auto createFoo = reinterpret_cast<FooFactory*>(lib.resolve("createFoo"));
```

And GCC tells me a `static_cast` is not allowed. So what should I do to avoid warnings in this case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since a cast is needed (and explicitly mentioned in the documentation) here, you can disable clang-tidy linting for this line explicitly with a description/reason:

```
const auto createFoo = (FooFactory*) lib.resolve("createFoo"); // NOLINT: allow casting of function pointers from QLibrary::resolve

// NOLINTNEXTLINE: allow casting of function pointers from QLibrary::resolve
const auto createFoo = (FooFactory*) lib.resolve("createFoo");
```

If you have the exact name of the warning, you can also disable just that specific one:

```
// NOLINTNEXTLINE(warning-name)
const auto createFoo = (FooFactory*) lib.resolve("createFoo");
```

More examples at the bottom of [the clang-tidy docs](https://clang.llvm.org/extra/clang-tidy/)

Comment: So there is no better way than disabling the warning? Is Clang-Tidy too pedantic here? And out of curiosity, could `QLibrary::resolve` return a better type than `void (*)()`?

Comment: Yes, clang-tidy is a bit too pedantic here, but that's because this is one of the very few exceptions. I guess you could extend clang-tidy to exclude QLibrary but that would introduce Qt specifics into a general linter which would probably be a bad idea.

Comment: `QLibrare::resolve` could be made a template with the casted-to-type as parameter, which would move the cast inside the function. But that only helps to silence such warnings and still leaves the responsibility of passing the correct type to the programmer. Such is life with explicit linking/loading. That's why OpenGL functions are usually loaded with a dedicated library which deals with that.